# Create Hierarchy from Ordered Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has parent-child relationship in one column.

I can use a row number that has been added when the file was loaded to sort the table into the correct order. 
I would like to get a full hierarchy from the column using the sort order

Sample Data

```
RowNumber   Type    Area           Name
1           1       Europe         Bob
2           2       Scotland       Bill
3           3       Edinburgh      Dave
4           2       England        Sharron
5           3       London         Tessa
6           2       Spain          Steve
7           2       Portugal       Carie
8           1       Asia           Helen
9           2       Thailand       John
1           2       Japan          Frank
11          3       Tokyo          Kate
12          3       Osaka          Brian
13          1       North America  Joe
```

I would like to be able to say exclude rows where level 1 = Asia.
Happy to use temporary tables or anything to get this working!

Help!

Comment: Can you maybe provide us with your expected results and queries you've tried to achieve this?

Comment: Did you neglect to show the parent-child relationship columns for some reason?   What is stopping you from saying "exclude rows where level 1 = Asia"?   Your question is way too unclear to answer right now.   I have no idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: I can';t see any relationships between rows in that data.

Comment: I *assume* `'Japan'` should be `RowNumber` `10`, not `1`?

Comment: Larnu, sorry yes. Japan should be 10. The relationship is only be row order. So level 2 is a child of the previous level 1 row. Level 3 is a child of the previous level 2 row etc. I want to get rid of anything that has a region of Asia. So Asia, Japan, Tokyo and asaka should all be removed

Answer (score 0):

I'm going by a guess on here, but it looks like you're looking for the previous level with a value of `type` 1 lower. This isn't how traditional hierarchical data is stored, so we need to fix that.

First some consumable Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SampleData (RowNumber int,
                             [Type] int,
                             Area varchar(30),
                             [name] varchar(30));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SampleData (RowNumber,
                            [Type],
                            Area,
                            [name])
VALUES(1,1,'Europe','Bob'),
      (2,2,'Scotland','Bill'),
      (3,3,'Edinburgh','Dave'),
      (4,2,'England','Sharron'),
      (5,3,'London','Tessa'),
      (6,2,'Spain','Steve'),
      (7,2,'Portugal','Carie'),
      (8,1,'Asia','Helen'),
      (9,2,'Thailand','John'),
      (10,2,'Japan','Frank'),
      (11,3,'Tokyo','Kate'),
      (12,3,'Osaka','Brian'),
      (13,1,'North America','Joe');
GO
```

Now we need to add a new column for the parent's ID (row number):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SampleData ADD ParentID int;
```

Then we need to populate that column:

```
UPDATE SD
SET ParentID = P.RowNumber
FROM dbo.SampleData SD
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ca.RowNumber
                  FROM dbo.SampleData ca
                  WHERE ca.[Type] = SD.[Type] - 1 
                    AND ca.RowNumber < SD.RowNumber
                  ORDER BY ca.RowNumber DESC) P;
```

Now we can achieve what you're after, such as getting all rows that aren't related to `'Asia'` by use of a rCTE (recursive Common Table Expression):

```
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT RowNumber,
           [Type],
           Area,
           [name]
    FROM dbo.SampleData
    WHERE [Type] = 1
      AND Area != 'Asia'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SD.RowNumber,
           SD.Type,
           SD.Area,
           SD.name
    FROM rCTE r
         JOIN dbo.SampleData SD ON r.RowNumber = SD.ParentID)
SELECT r.RowNumber,
       r.[Type],
       r.Area,
       r.[name]
FROM rCTE r;
```

Comment: I agree it isn't a proper hierarchy. That's the problem. I need to know each child's full hierarchy.

Comment: And that's why a created a proper hierarchy in the above to do so, @ScottB (using your data).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a known or maximum number of levels

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,ID  = RowNumber
      ,Pt  = choose( [Type]-1
                   ,max(case when [Type]=1 then RowNumber end) over (Order By RowNumber) 
                   ,max(case when [Type]=2 then RowNumber end) over (Order By RowNumber) 
                   ,max(case when [Type]=3 then RowNumber end) over (Order By RowNumber) 
                   ,max(case when [Type]=4 then RowNumber end) over (Order By RowNumber) 
                   ,max(case when [Type]=5 then RowNumber end) over (Order By RowNumber) 
                   )
 From YourTable A
```

**Returns**

[image]